# Latent heat and energy transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, water

Inside an insulated vessel at 1atm there is water at 100°C and a metal rod at 100°C, since temperature gradient is null there is no net heat transfer and water still liquid. In other words, in order to transmit latent heat, there must be a temperature difference. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, in order to transmit latent heat, there must be a
>   temperature difference. Am I right ?

That is correct. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference.

Since you asked this question specifically in connection with latent heat, I think you may be confusing the *requirements* for heat transfer to occur with the *results* of that heat transfer in terms of temperature changes.

If the rod was at a temperature greater than 100 C then it could transfer heat to the  water. But since the water is at its boiling point that transfer would not initially cause an increase the temperature of the water. Instead it would convert some liquid water to vapor vapor (steam) at constant temperature and pressure. That heat is then called the latent heat of vaporization.

On the other hand, if the water was below 100 C at 1 atm, heat transfer from the rod to the water would initially increase the temperature of the water until it reached its boiling point. The amount of heat required to raise the temperature of the water would be determined by the specific heat of water.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dear, you are right. The energy in the form of heat flows from one point to the other point in three modes i.e. conduction, convection, and radiation. The direction of heat transfer is always from a higher temperature to a lower temperature. If there is no temperature difference between the two points, there will be no heat transfer between them. As far as latent heats are concerned, they are substance-specific like melting point, boiling point, specific heat, etc.